# How to display 2d arrays with tkinter?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, tkinter

I am trying to make a maze game and I am using 2d arrays to store my mazes as functions, as I thought it would be the easiest solution. I don't know how to pack each function into a tkinter window so that the player can choose a place to move to by clicking a button (haven't gotten to that yet). My main problem is that I don't know how to access the 2d array.

```
import pygame, sys, tkinter
from tkinter import *

window = tkinter.Tk()


def visblock():
    icon = PhotoImage(file="Player_Icon.png")
    block = tkinter.Label(window, image=icon)
    return block
# These act like walls

def invisblock():
    icon = PhotoImage(file="Player_Icon_Cover.png")
    block = tkinter.Button(window, image=icon)
    return block
# These act like empty spaces"""

maze = [[visblock(), visblock(), visblock(), visblock()],
        [visblock(), invisblock(), invisblock(), visblock()],
        [invisblock(), invisblock(),visblock(), invisblock()],
        [visblock(), invisblock(), invisblock(), invisblock()],
        [visblock(),visblock(), visblock(), visblock()]]

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think this is the easiest way of doing what you're trying to do. Instead, try creating first a maze block object, then a maze object that combines blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way of displaying the buttons/labels created in the above code would be using the below code just before `window.mainloop()`:

```
for i, block_row in enumerate(maze):
    for j, block in enumerate(block_row):
        block.grid(row=i, column=j)
```

---

Also, note that tkinter needs images to have global references which the images you create haven't, further fix the code by adding global references to your images by modifying your methods to:

```
def visblock():
    block = tkinter.Label(window)
    block.image = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="Player_Icon.png")
    block['image'] = block.image
    return block
# These act like walls

def invisblock():
    block = tkinter.Button(window)
    block.image = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="Player_Icon_Cover.png")
    block['image'] = block.image
    return block
# These act like empty spaces"""
```

---

The entirety of the code should look like:

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()


def visblock():
    block = tkinter.Label(window)
    block.image = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="Player_Icon.png")
    block['image'] = block.image
    return block
# These act like walls

def invisblock():
    block = tkinter.Button(window)
    block.image = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="Player_Icon_Cover.png")
    block['image'] = block.image
    return block
# These act like empty spaces"""

maze = [[visblock(), visblock(), visblock(), visblock()],
        [visblock(), invisblock(), invisblock(), visblock()],
        [invisblock(), invisblock(),visblock(), invisblock()],
        [visblock(), invisblock(), invisblock(), invisblock()],
        [visblock(),visblock(), visblock(), visblock()]]

for i, block_row in enumerate(maze):
    for j, block in enumerate(block_row):
        block.grid(row=i, column=j)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been bothering me for what feels like ages